# Realize $SU(3)$ as a subgroup of $SO(6)$ (or $SO(7)$) in a surprising way

Tags: lie-groups, differential-forms, holonomy

Consider coordinates $z_k=x_k+iy_k (k=1,2,3)$ on $\mathbb C^3$. Consider a 2-form
$$
\omega = \sum_{k=1}^3 dx_k \wedge d y_k
$$
and a 3-form
$$
\rho= \mathrm{Im}(dz_1\wedge dz_2 \wedge dz_3)
$$
A surprising claim I encounter somewhere is that

> **Question 1:** $$ SU(3)=\{g\in SO(6) \mid g ~\text{preserves} ~\rho ~\text{and} ~\omega\} $$

How to show this? I only know this might be related to special holonomy stuffs, and my attempt is just to write everything explicitly in terms of matrices, but I believe that people may come up with better approaches. Especially I will appreciated it if you can provide any geometric explanation of this.

Moreover, consider $\mathbb R^7 = \mathbb C^3 \times \mathbb R$ with coordinates $(z_1,z_2,z_3,t)$, and then there is a similar question as follows:

> **Question 2:** $$ SU(3)=\{g\in SO(7) \mid g ~\text{preserves} ~\rho+ \omega dt ~\text{and} ~\partial_t \} $$

Comment: For $\omega$ part, it just describes the fact that $U(n)=SO(2n)\cap Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$, where $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$ is the symplectic group of degree $2n$ over $\mathbb{R}$, see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group). An analogous phenomenon appears when saying $Sp(n)=U(2n)\cap Sp(2n,\mathbb{C})$.